# Pair 2 devices via bluetooth using react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth

I'm new to `react-native` and I need to build an app that can pair 2 devices via **Bluetooth**. For what I know, to connect 2 devices via Bluetooth, one has to be on central mode and another on p**eripheral mode**.

All the libraries that I found just had the central mode option (e.g. `react-native-bluetooth-plx`), and I can't find any tutorials or info about this topic.

Can anyone here help me?

Comment: Hi Sérgio, welcome to the site! Have you seen `react-native-ble-peripheral`? I have not personally used it, so I won't post it as an answer (in our case we went with a native iOS app for the peripheral), but perhaps you will find it helpful.

Comment: Hey Marek! Yeah, I sent an email to the creator of that library. He said that it was meant to be an extension of `react-native-bluetooth-plx` , but the company wasn't interested on it, so he is no longer maintaining the library and it has a lot of issues/bugs. My team and I are now deciding if we stick with `react-native` and implement a native solution for the problem, or if we migrate to another framework to develop the app. Thank you anyway!